# How to reference a Cell in Excel using a User-Input Number

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I'm an intermediate Excel user, so you can assume I know the basics. I've got a table for a game that contains the level, and the experience required to get to that level from level 1. Basically I have the below:

Col A       Col B
Level       Experience Needed
1.             0
2.             10
3.             58
4.             160
5.             329
...
79.           551,002
80.           568,832

I was trying to make a simple UI in the cells themselves where you can just input your current level, input the level you want to get to, and have a formula calculate (essentially just the exp. required for the level you want minus the experience required to get to the current level)

I've searched and cannot find anything that will help me here. I'm sure there's a way (and probably a stupidly easy one) to do what I'm trying to do, but I am at a loss.

What I pictured in my head was something that just took the number input and put that to the cell reference (eg. input 44 and it would then reference B44)

I was hoping for something in-cell, but if it needs to be code in VisualBasic I can get over it (just not really comfortable programming!)

Thanks in advance for the help!

Edit: Can either be in Excel or Google Sheets, not sure if either is easier/harder than the other.

Comment: I think you are looking for the INDIRECT function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put current level in cell `E1` and desired level in `E2` The following formula will pull the values out of the Experience Needed column and subtract them. Is that what you are looking for?

```
=INDIRECT("B"&E2+1)-INDIRECT("B"&E1+1)
```

Comment: Yes, that works perfectly, thank you!

I found the indirect function when searching but apparently can't read documentation correctly and couldn't get it to work, so I assumed it was the wrong formula and not human error lol

Thanks again.